# How to host windows services to windows azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, windows-services

How to host windows services to windows azure.

I found many solution related to Worker role but Worker role have many setup like

1. Create Worker Role Solution.
2. Create Cloud Service to run script.

Is there any simple way to host windows service to windows azure like we are installing services using Installutil.exe and Start and Stop using Service Manager.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you want is install a Windows Service in an existing cloud service (may be a web role) without having to do it in a worker role. Is my understanding correct? Or you don't even want a web role and just want to install and run a Windows Service anywhere in Azure.

Comment: Yes I want to run my windows service to windows azure by any simple way.

Comment: `I want to run my windows service to windows azure by any simple way` - This is a pretty vague comment IMHO. Give us more details about the application. Do you intend to run it as a cloud service or in a VM? Then it may be possible to give you some suggestions.

Comment: I created one Windows Service Solution in my project. That will run in every 5 min.I want to host that windows service to Windows azure.

Answer (score 2):

For running your Windows Service in Azure, you could simply take a Virtual Machine (not Cloud Service) with either Windows Server 2012 or 2008 OS. Remote desktop into the server and install your service as you would do on your local computer. You don't have to do anything special for this.

Comment: Ok. Thanks I will do it this way.

Comment: So i just have to take Release folder on windows azure virtual machine using Remote Desktop and then use command like this :installutil.exe MyNewService.exe  ???